# How to determine if RarInfo is belong to more than one part using python rarfile?

Tags: python, rar

When reading a multipart rar file using python rarfile, calling `infolist()`
returns RarInfo objects for all files/directories in archive. Using `volume` property, one can determine which part a particular RarInfo object's start bytes is belong to; but I can't find a property that shows the part which that object is ending on. so how to determine if a RarInfo object is belonged to more than one part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there could be a property or method in rarfile module which I'm not aware of, But I did what I was up to using `unrar.exe` & `subprocces`:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen(['unrar.exe', 'lb', <RAR FILE NAME PART X>], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
output, err = p.communicate(b"input data that is passed to subprocess' stdin")
rc = p.returncode
output = output.decode("utf-8").split('\r\n')[:-1]
```

running this for each part, gives you a list of file names contained in each part, then you can loop through them to find which files appeared in more than one part!

---

NOTE: I've used unrar.exe delivered by WinRAR, available on it's installation directory; Adding that directory to system PATH will result in using just unrar.exe in Popen.